# Where is the external code (unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor) for TensorFlow github:

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to get the TensorFlow GitHub code and compile it on my local Windows machine.

I currently have problems with the following include:

```
#include "external/eigen_archive/eigen-eigen-ce5a455b34c0/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"
```

Where can this file be found?

Comment: For status of TensorFlow on Windows see: [TensorFlow Issue #17: Windows Support and Documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17)

Comment: I found this looking through the Jenkins build info: [Tesnor file](http://ci.tensorflow.org/job/tensorflow-master/ws/bazel-tensorflow/external/eigen_archive/eigen-eigen-ce5a455b34c0/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor/*view*/) || [Directory](http://ci.tensorflow.org/job/tensorflow-master/ws/bazel-tensorflow/external/eigen_archive/eigen-eigen-ce5a455b34c0/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/)

Comment: on a working session of bazel you can use`cd $(bazel info output_base)/external/eigen_archive/` to get to eigen_archive then you should see the file in question. However in my session I do not have the folder eigen-eigen-ceetc. and I cannot make the example run either. I refer you to the the end of the discussion [link](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/623)

Answer (score 0):

Eigen is downloaded from bitbucket by bazel. Version ce5a455 corresponds to the [3.3-beta1 release](http://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/3.3-beta1.tar.bz2) of the Eigen codebase, which had some issues. As of today, TensorFlow is pulling [this newer version](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/5651786.tar.gz). Let me know if you still experience problems and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

please run the shell below first

tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_%os_name%.sh