# Implementation of tf.extract_image_patches

Tags: python, tensorflow, eigen

Where is the implementation of `tf.extract_image_patches`? I checked the tensorflow repository I could not find it.

The file `tensorflow/core/kernels/extract_image_patches_op.cc` does not contain an implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's an interesting question. The path is as follows:

- Python [`tf.extract_image_patches`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/extract_image_patches) function is implemented in the generated file `tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py`, which invokes `"ExtractImagePatches"` native op.
- This op is implemented by `ExtractImagePatchesOp` in [`core/kernels/extract_image_patches_op.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/extract_image_patches_op.cc#L50) for both CPU and GPU devices. The main call is `functor::ExtractImagePatchesForward`...
- ... which is defined in [`core/kernels/extract_image_patches_op.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5e855c56c2657128ff793b83442edc9886808922/tensorflow/core/kernels/extract_image_patches_op.h#L26). The actual logic is delegated to the `::extract_image_patches()` method of the input tensor. The tensor's type is `TTypes<T, 4>::ConstTensor`, which is a typedef of `Eigen::TensorMap` [`core/framework/tensor_types.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5e855c56c2657128ff793b83442edc9886808922/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_types.h#L29).

At this point, it's getting out of tensorflow source base, because `Eigen` is from the third-party [eigen library](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/) ([GitHub mirror](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/eigen-mirror)). Its source code is somewhat [non-trivially downloaded and linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34689114/712995) to tensorflow, but right now we are interested in `Eigen::TensorMap::extract_image_patches()` function.

- It's defined in [`eigen/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorBase.h`](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/2784ec4bdf50a92acfd0dd2396a81ffc3e1b993a/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorBase.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#TensorBase.h-706) file and applies `TensorImagePatchOp`...
- ... which can be found in [`eigen/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorImagePatch.h`](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/2784ec4bdf50a92acfd0dd2396a81ffc3e1b993a/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorImagePatch.h?fileviewer=file-view-default). Finally, this functor doesn't delegate it further, i.e. the actual implementation.

Note that particular version of `Eigen` library may be different in different builds of tensorflow, which you should check in the bazel config.